# Is it possible to hover multiple (two) buttons on an image?

Tags: css

I have a responsive page where I want to place "save" and "delete" icons as buttons on top of images. Any ideas how that could be managed, even when the page resizes?

Comment: I edited the question to make more clear what I think you are really asking, but feel free to roll back or to edit further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this.

```css
.button {
position:absolute;
background-color:red;
top:0;
left:0;
width:50px;
height:80px;
}

.right {
left:120px}

.name-me {
position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="name-me">
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MOf9Kxxkj7GvyZlTZOnUzuYv0JAweEhlxJX6gslQvbvlhLK5_bSTK6duxY2xfbBsj43H=w300">

<div class="button left"></div>
<div class="button right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Resizing doesn't affect the event of  button..Better you can use bootstrap glyphicons for save and delete icons. Thats much more easy for do the responsive. **http://getbootstrap.com/components/** This is the basic glyphicons using in bootstrap...
 (or)
Put the image inside the link('a attribute') and then **change the opacity of the image on hover**